# Windows Git uninitialized constant (NameError)

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby and getting this error. I am in Windows 10 using Git.

This is my code:

```
print "What's your name? "
name = gets.chomp
print "How old are you? "
age = gets.chomp
puts = "Your name is #{Matthew Farmer}, and your age is #{age}"
```

I can get it to ask both my name and age, but it keeps coming back as
`gets.rb:7:in '<main>': uninitialized constant Farmer (NameError)`.

Comment: What does this have to do with git?

Comment: Well, with Windows there is no terminal like Apple and Linux have. I downloaded Git, so that I could code in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't interpolate the `name` local variable, and you are assigning the value of a string to `puts`:

```
print "What's your name? "
name = gets.chomp
print "How old are you? "
age = gets.chomp
puts "Your name is #{name}, and your age is #{age}" # remove = ; change Matthew Farmer to name
```

Comment: Thanks orde, I was following a tutorial and I don't recall him changing it back to "name". I'll try this as soon as I get home and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks again orde!